# How to stop Word from losing pictures pasted in from Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-word-2007, image-editing

I am using Word 2007 and Outlook 2007. If someone emails me an image in message body text, and I then copy the image into a Word document, initially the image appears but eventually Word replaces the image with a blank space and an error: "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location." Why does Word lose the image? [The workaround is to print the email to a PDF, take a snapshot of the image, and paste that into Word, but is there a better way?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying it from Outlook, use the option: Paste it as picture.

[image]

Comment: Curious: Why does the default (paste as HTML) result in Word eventually losing the image?

Answer (score 2):

Save the image to your hard drive by right clicking the image and choosing save image to hard drive then add it to word